# How do display different mysql table rows on a page, in the order they where inserted

Tags: php, mysql, html

How do social network like facebook display different content, such as photos, status, user activities onto the page, in the order it was originally posted. I have done a lot research but can't seem to find any good examples on how it's done using PHP and MYSQL.

I have include a visual example of what i mean.
[image: visual example]

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean? The chronological sorting is usually done using an ORDER statement of some sort in the query that collects the posts. What the query needs to look like, pretty much depends on the data structure used...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you mean is that the different contents are in separate tables like photos, status updates, newconnections etc. And you want the final wall to pull data from all these tables into a single wall in the same chronological order of time. So, what I will suggest is to create a new table for the wall with the following main fields :

`Activity_identifier`,`activity_id` and `timestamp`. Here `Activity_identifier` is the predefined identity of the activity such as sharing a photo (lets say 1), posting on the wall (lets say 2) etc and `timestamp` is the time when that  activity was recorded by the user, and `activity_id` is the id of that activity in the corresponding table.

Everytime a new activity is created by the user, while populating the corresponding table for that activity, also record a corresponding entry in this table for wall.

Now your final query to create the wall will just have to call this new table for wall with `ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC`, then the resulting data needs to be joined with other activity tables (use `Activity_identifier` intelligently here) through the foreign-key `activity_id` to recreate the wall in the exact chronological order that the user created them.

For incremental call to the wall, maintain a timestamp of last query (lets say *xtime*) and every call do `timestamp > xtime ... ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much, That really helped a lot. I will post my full working code after am done.

Comment: Nice job divining the "real" question and providing a powerful solution in a concise form (and without writing all of the poster's code for them).

Answer (score 0):

When they do the query they have an ORDER BY clause. EG:

```
SELECT `photos`
FROM `submissions`
ORDER BY `dateline` DESC
```

`dateline` can be stored as an integer [unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and then used with simple math to set additional parameters. EG:

```
$sql = "SELECT `photos`
FROM `submissions`
WHERE `dateline` >= " . (date() - 60*60*24*7) . "
ORDER BY `dateline` DESC";
```

This would give you only submissions from the past week.

Answer (score 0):

Use timestamp column and keep track of each entry's insertion time in your code.
When querying data, `ORDER BY` timestamp column.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply store a field in database which contains timestamp or creation date when specyfied content was created and while selecting it from DB just order it by mentioned creation_date :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Timestamps](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) fields in your tables (at least that's what i do) alogn with every insert (or update), with a default value of [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html), this will let you sort by date (and time) of insertion with simple SQL statements

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as publishers and subscribers. Each message has a list of receivers in a junction table.

```
Message
------------
message_id
message_body

Message_receivers
------------
message_id
user_id

Message_photos
------------
message_id
photo
```

Here's how I get messages for me (user_id 1):

```
SELECT m.*, mp.*
  FROM Message m
  JOIN Message_receivers mr
    ON mr.message_id = m.message_id AND mr.user_id = 1
  LEFT JOIN Message_photos mp
    ON mp.message_id = m.message_id
  ORDER BY m.message_id DESC
```

You update these lists when the user posts rather than try to build the list when a user reads their news feed, since even though you may have a lot of posts, you will have more reads.

The Message_receivers records will expire and roll off. The news feed only goes back so far, though if you go to a user's page, you can see all of their posts.